# Eclipse file search - How do I search for a particular string

Tags: regex, eclipse, search

In `Eclipse`, using the `File Search` feature, I am trying to do a file search over a large package for files containing `<button` and `class="someclass"`, **but without** `type="button"`.

In a more general sense, how do I search for some text while excluding results of they contain another bit of text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>CTRL + H</kbd> and then choose *File Search*, there you can check the *Regular expression* option.

In order to get what you want, you can try entering something like this:

**^(?!.*type="button").*class="someclass".*$**

You can get more general regex information for Eclipse's File Search at [this page](http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/home/downloads/installguide/gla_42/ref/rregexp.html).

Comment: Yes, but how do I form the regex?